asus ZenBook kubuntu 24.04 (6.8.0-36) suddenly hanging in Boot with no manual update
Hardware:
ASUS ZenBook Pro Duo UX581GV
OS:
kubuntu 24.04 (GNU/Linux 6.8.0-36-generic x86_64)
Yesterday my laptop did work normally.
This morning it does not boot fully any more.
It just stops somewhere.
I can switch to a second terminal (alt+f2)
And can login there.
I disabled two of the last shown systems services. But this did not change anything.
i also booted into recovery and did a repair packages and a disk clean (get some space back)
The us about 30GB free..
And in my second login I did a sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade.
Both fine..
I also tried booting in the previous kernel versioning  6.8.0-35 but this was the exact same behavior.
My feeling is that this has something to do with graph..
As this is not the first time I have problems with the nvidia drivers..
Has anybody good idea how to go on from here?
What to do next?

thanks to bash history:
i scrolled back and found what i have done..
on my laptop i have a custom config for my touchscrens
copied to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-touch_pen_input.conf
yesterday i changed a line in there and this created a invalid config.
and this invalid config seems to stops somehow the startup of my system..
without a error message visible in the on-screen-visible log.
i today verified this behavior:
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier                      "BottomTouchScreen_Mapping"
        MatchProduct                    "ELAN9009:00 04F3:29A1"
        MatchIsTouchscreen              "on"
        #Option "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.337423, 0.662577, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
EndSection

if i uncomment the line  #Option "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1.00.... my system does not start anymore...
seems the Option-name is invalid and therefore leads to this behavior.
